# Optimize Google Scripts - Triggers not working

Tags: google-apps-script

**Problem**

My Google Script triggers aren't running because it "uses to much CPU time", according to error emails I receive. How can I optimize my scripts to use less CPU time?
I've separated `sortGsheetFiles` into different trigger, but it still uses to much time. It used to be combined with the `importXLSXtoGsheet` function.

**Scripts explained**

I've got 52 folders, each containing one spreadsheet file.
Each folder is shared with different colleagues.
During the day, people make changes to the files.

1. At the end of the day, all files are collected in one folder (`gsheetFolder`) and converted to XLSX files, using the function `collectAndExportXLS`.

These files are copied to a local server in the evening (using batch script and drive sync) which updates other information in the file and are copied back to the `importXLSXfolder`.

2. In the morning the `importXLSXtoGsheet` function runs and converts all XLSX files in the `importXLSXfolder` folder to Gsheet files in the `gsheetFolder`.
3. After that `sortGsheetFiles` runs, sorting and moving every Gsheet file in one of the 52 folders (using an array list from the current spreadsheet).

Other actions include cleaning the folders with the `deleteFolder` function.

**Triggers**

`importXLSXtoGsheet` - every day - between 6 am and 7 am
`sortGsheetFiles` - every day - between 7 am and 8 am
`collectAndExportXLS` - every day - between 10 pm and 11 pm

**Script**

```
var gsheetFolder = 'xxx';
var XLSXfolder = 'xxxxx';
var importXLSXfolder = 'xxxxx';

function checkEmptyFolder() {

var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders()
  for(n=0;n<folders.length;++n){
    if(folders[n].getFiles().length==0 && folders[n].getFolders().length==0){
     folders[n].setTrashed(true)
     Logger.log(folders[n].getName())
     }
   }  
}

function importXLSXtoGsheet(){

// ========= convert all XLS files in XLS folder to GSheet and put in the general gsheet folder - after that sort in gsheet filiaal folders =========
// cleanup exportXLS folder first 
  deleteFolder(XLSXfolder);

  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(importXLSXfolder).searchFiles('title contains ".xlsx"');
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')) { 
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {
        title : name + ('.xlsx'),
        key : ID,
        parents: [{"id": gsheetFolder}]
      }
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {convert: true});
    }
  }
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

function sortGsheetFiles() {

  // ========= sort Gsheet folder and move to corresponding filiaal folders =========

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var myArrayFileName = sheet.getRange("A2:A53").getValues();
  var myArrayFolderId = sheet.getRange("B2:B53").getValues();
  var a = myArrayFileName.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
  var b = myArrayFolderId.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

  var folderId = gsheetFolder;
  // Log the name of every file in the folder. 
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();

     while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
        for (var i in a) {
          var id = file.getId();
          if (file.getName() == a[i]) { 
            moveFiles(id, b[i]); // Match found and move to corresponding folder
          }
        }
     }
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

function collectAndExportXLS() {
  // ========= collect all Gsheet files, copy to gsheet folder and convert to xlsx and move to xlsx folder =========

  // cleanup gsheet folder
  deleteFolder(gsheetFolder);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var myArrayFileName = sheet.getRange("A2:A53").getValues();
  var myArrayFolderId = sheet.getRange("B2:B53").getValues();
  var a = myArrayFileName.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
  var b = myArrayFolderId.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

  var folderId = gsheetFolder;

  for (var i in b) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(b[i]).getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var id = file.getId();
      moveFiles(id , folderId);
    }
  }
  ConvertBackToXLS()
  deleteFolder(gsheetFolder);

}

function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);
}

function deleteFolder(folder) {
  //delete files in a folder without sending to trash!

  var eachFile, idToDLET, myFolder, rtrnFromDLET, thisFile, files;
  files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder).getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {//If there is another element in the iterator
    eachFile = files.next();
    idToDLET = eachFile.getId();
    //Logger.log('idToDLET: ' + idToDLET);

    rtrnFromDLET = Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);
  };
   Logger.log('folder deleted');
}

function ConvertBackToXLS() {

  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(gsheetFolder).getFiles();
  var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById(XLSXfolder);
  while (files.hasNext()) {

     try {
     var file = files.next(); 
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
     Logger.log(file.getId());
     var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + file.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
     var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(ss.getName());  
    var newfile = dir.createFile(blob); 

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You run the functions of ``importXLStoGsheet``, ``sortGsheetFiles`` and ``collectAndExportXLS`` by 3 time-driven triggers. From this situation, can I ask you about each average execution time? By the way, ``importXLStoGsheet`` is ``importXLSXtoGsheet`` in your script?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. `importXLStoGsheet ` should be `importXLSXtoGsheet`. Execution times: `importXLSXtoGsheet` takes 352 seconds. `sortGsheetFiles` takes 92 seconds. `collectAndExportXLS` takes 372 seconds

Comment: do you need to do the push conversion? or would it be possible to modify a master gsheet with the new information and copy it out from there. (I'm assuming the convert to xslx and store is not negotiable for backup reasons)

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand your situation. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this modification is not the result you want, I apologize. If the error occurred, can you provide the detail information for replicating it? About this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

**And as an important point, please test the script using a test situation, before you run with your actual situation.**

### About your script:

1. `collectAndExportXLS()`: Abou this function name, I didn't modify `collectAndExportXLS()`. Because I thought that you might be using this function name at other script or triggers.

   1. Delete all files in `gsheetFolder`.
   2. Convert a Google Spreadsheet in each folder ID retrieved from "B2:B53" of the sheet with the 1st index in the active Spreadsheet to XLSX format.

      - Filename is like `sample.xlsx`.
      - All converted files are put in `XLSXfolder`.
   3. Delete all files in all folder IDs.
   4. **XLSX files in `XLSXfolder` are put in `importXLSXfolder` by other script.**
2. `importXLSXtoGsheet()`: Abou this function name, I didn't modify `collectAndExportXLS()`. Because I thought that you might be using this function name at other script or triggers.

   1. Delete all files in `XLSXfolder`.
   2. Convert all XLSX files in `importXLSXfolder` to Google Spreadsheet.

      - Filename is like `sample.xlsx`.
      - Converted Google Spreadsheets are put in `gsheetFolder`.
   3. Delete all files in `importXLSXfolder`.
3. `sortGsheetFiles()`

   1. Move Google Spreadsheets in `gsheetFolder` to each folder ID retrieved from "B2:B53" of the sheet with the 1st index in the active Spreadsheet.

      - In order to match the folder ID, the filenames of Google Spreadsheet and the values retrieved from "A2:A53".
   2. Delete all files in `importXLSXfolder`.
4. I understood that from your question, the filenames of column "A2:A53" of the active Spreadsheet are the same with the filenames of Google Spreadsheets which were put in the folders of folder IDs of the column "B2:B53".
5. I understood that the number of all files is less than 100.

I understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In my modification, I used the Batch request of Drive API and the fetchAll method of UrlFetchApp with the type of `multipart/form-data` for your situation. The batch request and fetchAll method can work with the asynchronous process. By this, I thought that your process cost might be reduced.

In order to use these methods, I used 2 GAS libraries. Before you run the script, please install these 2 libraries for your script. You can see how to install the library as follows.

1. [Install a library for running the fetchAll method of UrlFetchApp with the type of `multipart/form-data`.](https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp#how-to-install)
2. [Install a library for running batch request.](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)

### Modification points:

- `collectAndExportXLS()`

  - File IDs in each folder are retrieved by the batch request.
  - Blobs (XLSX format) from each file ID are retrieved by the fetchAll method of UrlFetchApp.
  - Files of XLSX format are created by FetchApp.
- `importXLSXtoGsheet()`

  - File list is retrieved by the files.list method of Drive API.
  - Files of XLSX format are converted to Google Spreadsheet by the batch request.
- `sortGsheetFiles()`

  - File list is retrieved by the files.list method of Drive API.
  - Files of Google Spreadsheet are moved to each folder ID retrieved from the column "B2:B53" of the active Spreadsheet using the batch request.
- `deleteFolder()`

  - Files in the folder are deleted by the batch request.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

After installed 2 libraries, please run the following script.

```
var gsheetFolder = '###';
var XLSXfolder = '###';
var importXLSXfolder = '###';

// Modified
function deleteFolder(folderId) {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + folderId + "'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files%2Fid&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var reqs = obj.files.map(function(e) {return {method: "DELETE", endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id}});
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
}

// Added
function deleteFiles(files) {
  var reqs = files.map(function(e) {return {method: "DELETE", endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id}});
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
}

// Added
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  return sheet.getRange("A2:B53").getValues();
}

// Modified
function sortGsheetFiles() {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + gsheetFolder + "'+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D'" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var values = getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  var reqs = values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
      if (obj.files[i].name == e[0]) {
        ar.push({
          method: "PATCH",
          endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + obj.files[i].id + "?addParents=" + e[1] + "&removeParents=" + gsheetFolder,
        });
        break;
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

// Modified
function importXLSXtoGsheet(){
  deleteFolder(XLSXfolder);
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + importXLSXfolder + "'+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D'" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "'+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var reqs = obj.files.map(function(e) {return {
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id + "/copy",
      requestBody: {mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, name: e.name + ".xlsx", parents: [gsheetFolder]},
    }
  });
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

// Modified
function ConvertBackToXLS(fileList) {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var reqs1 = fileList.map(function(e) {return {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=" + e.id + "&exportFormat=xlsx&access_token=" + token,
    }
  });
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs1);
  var reqs2 = res.map(function(e, i) {
    var metadata = {name: fileList[i].name, parents: [XLSXfolder]};
    var form = FetchApp.createFormData(); // Create form data
    form.append("metadata", Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(metadata), "application/json"));
    form.append("file", e.getBlob());
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart";
    return {url: url, method: "POST", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + token}, body: form};
  });
  FetchApp.fetchAll(reqs2);
}

// Modified
function collectAndExportXLS() {
  deleteFolder(gsheetFolder);
  var values = getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  var reqs1 = values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0] && e[1]) {
      ar.push({
        method: "GET",
        endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + e[1] + "'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)",
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var resForReq1 = BatchRequest.Do({batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs1});
  var temp = resForReq1.getContentText().split("--batch");
  var files = temp.slice(1, temp.length - 1).map(function(e) {return JSON.parse(e.match(/{[\S\s]+}/g)[0])});
  var fileList = files.reduce(function(ar, e) {return ar.concat(e.files.map(function(f) {return f}))}, []);
  ConvertBackToXLS(fileList);
  deleteFiles(fileList);
}
```

### Note:

- In this modification, the error handling is not reflected, because I couldn't test your situation. So please add it, if you are required.
- If the file size of XLSX files is large, the error might occur.

### References:

- [Batch request of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- [FetchApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp)

Comment: Thank you again for your extended answer! I really appreciate your effort.
I've created a test environment and added your libraries.
After I ran `collectAndExportXLS`, I didn't see any converted files, but also no errors. I'm going to do some debugging and get back to this.

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for replying. And I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked fine, again. I apologize for this situation. So if your issue was not resolved, please tell me. At that time, please provide the method for replicating your issue. By this, I would like to test it and find the solution of your issue.

Comment: Weird, I've copied the script again, checked everything and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, to

Comment: Unfortunately I saw last weekend that every day the function `importXLStoGsheet()` resulted in a error: `Error: Exception: Time-out: https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3 at [unknown function](Code:63) at Do(Code:8) at importXLSXtoGsheet(Code:71)` - average runtime was around 60 seconds.

Comment: If I run the function manually, it show the same error, while last week it ran without problems?

Comment: @Bldjef Unfortunately, from your comments, I couldn't understand about your situation. Because in my environment, the script works file. I could also confirm this now. I would like to confirm your situation. So can you post it as new question including the detail information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to check it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Bldjef Now I confirmed about the script, again. I could confirm that the script (collectAndExportXLS(), importXLSXtoGsheet() and sortGsheetFiles()) worked fine, again. Although I tested several situations, I couldn't replicate your situation. I apologize for this situation. This is due to my poor skill. So can you post new question including the detail information for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted a new question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110759/google-script-timeouts

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for your response. I confirm and test it and when I found the reason of the issue, I would like to report it to the new question.