# Google Script timeouts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

**Problem:**

The import function `importXLSXtoGsheet()` times out before it can process all 52 XLSX files, I received the error:
`Exception: Time-out: https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3 at [unknown function](Code:63) at Do(Code:8) at importXLSXtoGsheet(Code:71)`

If I run the function with 1 file in the importXLS folder, it works correctly.

**Script explained:**

I've got 52 folders, each containing one spreadsheet file.
Each folder is shared with different colleagues.
During the day, people make changes to the files.

1. At the end of the day, all files are collected in one folder (`gsheetFolder`) and converted to XLSX files, using the function `collectAndExportXLS`.

These files are copied to a local server in the evening (using batch script and drive sync) which updates other information in the file and are copied back to the `importXLSXfolder`.

2. In the morning the `importXLSXtoGsheet` function runs and converts all XLSX files in the `importXLSXfolder` folder to Gsheet files in the `gsheetFolder`.
3. After that `sortGsheetFiles` runs, sorting and moving every Gsheet file in one of the 52 folders (using an array list from the current spreadsheet).

Other actions include cleaning the folders with the `deleteFolder` function.

**Script:**

```
var gsheetFolder = '###';
var XLSXfolder = '###';
var importXLSXfolder = '###';

// Modified
function deleteFolder(folderId) {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + folderId + "'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files%2Fid&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var reqs = obj.files.map(function(e) {return {method: "DELETE", endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id}});
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
}

// Added
function deleteFiles(files) {
  var reqs = files.map(function(e) {return {method: "DELETE", endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id}});
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
}

// Added
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  return sheet.getRange("A2:B53").getValues();
}

// Modified
function sortGsheetFiles() {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + gsheetFolder + "'+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D'" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var values = getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  var reqs = values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
      if (obj.files[i].name == e[0]) {
        ar.push({
          method: "PATCH",
          endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + obj.files[i].id + "?addParents=" + e[1] + "&removeParents=" + gsheetFolder,
        });
        break;
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

// Modified
function importXLSXtoGsheet(){
  deleteFolder(XLSXfolder);
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + importXLSXfolder + "'+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D'" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "'+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var reqs = obj.files.map(function(e) {return {
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id + "/copy",
      requestBody: {mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, name: e.name + ".xlsx", parents: [gsheetFolder]},
    }
  });
  var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
  if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}

// Modified
function ConvertBackToXLS(fileList) {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var reqs1 = fileList.map(function(e) {return {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=" + e.id + "&exportFormat=xlsx&access_token=" + token,
    }
  });
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs1);
  var reqs2 = res.map(function(e, i) {
    var metadata = {name: fileList[i].name, parents: [XLSXfolder]};
    var form = FetchApp.createFormData(); // Create form data
    form.append("metadata", Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(metadata), "application/json"));
    form.append("file", e.getBlob());
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart";
    return {url: url, method: "POST", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + token}, body: form};
  });
  FetchApp.fetchAll(reqs2);
}

// Modified
function collectAndExportXLS() {
  deleteFolder(gsheetFolder);
  var values = getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  var reqs1 = values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0] && e[1]) {
      ar.push({
        method: "GET",
        endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + e[1] + "'+in+parents+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)",
      });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var resForReq1 = BatchRequest.Do({batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs1});
  var temp = resForReq1.getContentText().split("--batch");
  var files = temp.slice(1, temp.length - 1).map(function(e) {return JSON.parse(e.match(/{[\S\s]+}/g)[0])});
  var fileList = files.reduce(function(ar, e) {return ar.concat(e.files.map(function(f) {return f}))}, []);
  ConvertBackToXLS(fileList);
  deleteFiles(fileList);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the maximum number of files when the error doesn't occur? Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, by this result, for example, how about deciding the maximum number for processing the files once?

Comment: It runs fine with 13 files, but with 14 or more it fails.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Using the value, how about deciding the maximum number for processing the files once?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that. You mean I should do the import in batches of 10 files for example?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script for your issue as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I cannot test this script. So if this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question, I could understand like below.

- When `importXLSXtoGsheet()` is run with 52 files, the error occurs.
- When `importXLSXtoGsheet()` is run with less than 13 files, no error occurs.
- Other functions except for `importXLSXtoGsheet()` works fine.

If my understanding is correct, as one workaround, it decides the maximum number for processing the files once. When this is reflect to `importXLSXtoGsheet()` of your script, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function importXLSXtoGsheet(){
  deleteFolder(XLSXfolder);
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + importXLSXfolder + "'+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D'" + MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL + "'+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=files(id%2Cname)&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

  // I modified below script.
  var n = 10; // Maximum number.
  var files = [];
  var len = obj.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    files.push(obj.files.splice(0, n));
    len -= n - 1;
  }
  files.forEach(function(f) {
    var reqs = f.map(function(e) {return {
        method: "POST",
        endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e.id + "/copy",
        requestBody: {mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, name: e.name + ".xlsx", parents: [gsheetFolder]},
      }
    });
    var requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
    if (requests.requests.length > 0) BatchRequest.Do(requests);
  });
  deleteFolder(importXLSXfolder);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, 10 files are processed every batch request. If you want to change this, please modify `var n = 10;`.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tested it and it works like a charm! I'm going to check if the trigger works as well this week.

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for replying. If the same error occurs when you test it by the trigger, please modify ``var n = 10``.